# Best config for ffmpeg to convert MP3 file only

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to compile FFMPEG to support conversion from MP3 to WAV and WAV to MP3.

as I only need that task, and output compiled size is really matter to me, Please correct me best compile config that accompilesh my requirement.

here is full config file:

```
function build_ffmpeg
{
    echo "Starting build ffmpeg for $ARCH"
    cd ffmpeg
    ./configure --target-os=linux \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --enable-cross-compile \
        --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
        --arch=$ARCH \
        --cc=$CC \
        --cross-prefix=$CROSS_COMPILE \
        --nm=$NM \
        --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
        --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
        --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog -L$PREFIX/lib" \
        --extra-cflags="-I$PREFIX/include" \
        --disable-everything \
        --enable-pthreads \
        --enable-libass \
        --enable-libvo-aacenc \
        --enable-libvo-amrwbenc \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_dxva2 \
        --enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vaapi \
        --enable-demuxer=mov \
        --enable-demuxer=h264 \
        --enable-demuxer=mpegvideo \
        --enable-demuxer=h263 \
        --enable-demuxer=mpegps \
        --enable-demuxer=mjpeg \
        --enable-demuxer=rtsp \
        --enable-demuxer=rtp \
        --enable-demuxer=hls \
        --enable-demuxer=matroska \
        --enable-muxer=rtsp \
        --enable-muxer=mp4 \
        --enable-muxer=mov \
        --enable-muxer=mjpeg \
        --enable-muxer=matroska \
        --enable-protocol=crypto \
        --enable-protocol=jni \
        --enable-protocol=file \
        --enable-encoder=libvo_amrwbenc \
        --enable-decoder=amrwb \
        --enable-muxer=mp2 \
        --enable-bsfs \
        --enable-decoders \
        --enable-encoders \
        --enable-parsers \
        --enable-hwaccels \
        --enable-muxers \
        --enable-avformat \
        --enable-avcodec \
        --enable-avresample \
        --enable-zlib \
        --disable-doc \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-ffmpeg \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-ffprobe \
        --disable-ffserver \
        --disable-avfilter \
        --disable-avdevice \
        --enable-nonfree \
        --enable-version3 \
        --enable-memalign-hack \
        --enable-asm \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
    make clean
    make -j4 install
    make clean

    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED ffmpeg for $ARCH"
}

function build_one {
    echo "Starting build one for $ARCH"
    cd ffmpeg
    ${LD} -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PREFIX/lib  -soname $SONAME -shared -nostdlib -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $OUT_LIBRARY -lavcodec -lavformat -lavresample -lavutil -lswresample -lass -lfreetype -lfribidi -lswscale -lvo-aacenc -lvo-amrwbenc -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -zmuldefs $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/$EABIARCH/$COMPILATOR_VERSION/libgcc.a
    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED one for $ARCH"
}
```

Comment: What about using simpler, dedicated tools such as mpg123 or similar to decode and lame or shineenc to encode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
./configure --disable-all --disable-autodetect --disable-network --enable-pthreads \
  --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-swresample --enable-avfilter \
  --enable-libmp3lame --enable-parser=mpegaudio --enable-demuxer=mp3,wav \
  --enable-muxer=mp3,wav --enable-decoder=pcm*,mp3* --enable-encoder=pcm*,libmp3lame \
  --enable-filter=aresample --enable-protocol=file --enable-ffmpeg --enable-small
```

- Consider using libshine instead of libmp3lame is you need faster, but lower quality, MP3 encoding (especially on architectures without a FPU).
- I usually don't recommend using `--disable-all`, but the size of the executable seems to be the most important factor for you. Using `--disable-everything` is easier to use because it does not disable the FFmpeg libraries, and is therefore less prone to forgotten components.
- `--disable-small` optimizes for size instead of speed. It does make a size difference (1 MB vs 1.4 MB in this example), but I'm not sure how much of a speed difference it makes.
- I did not include any additional options you may need for compiling for or on Android.
- This may not work for MP3 inputs that contain album art because I did not enable any video options (specifically JPG and PNG related components). You may get by that by mapping just the audio with the `-map` option, such as with `-map 0:a`.

Comment: I have a problem while compiling the ffmpeg, it shows the checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/root/ffmpeg/AndroidFFmpeg/library-jni/jni/liblame':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
.

Comment: do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: I am using ubunto 16

Comment: @LordNeckbread, thanks, the problem solved with checking config.log, but the output ffmpeg file do not convert mp3 to wav, please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009128/unable-to-convert-mp3-file-to-pcm-with-ffmpeg

Comment: @Ata You didn't mention that you wanted s16le (pcm) output so I did not include it. There was no need to make a new question: just a comment would have sufficed and I would have updated this answer.

Comment: thanks, have you updated that? I did not noticed anything

Comment: @Ata No, because it was already answered in your other question.

Comment: thanks, it works well and I have no problem with encoding and decoding. also I have a question, I used that in android version with this requesto to convert file : -y -i [path] -b:a 128k [output] . but the speed is 4.8 x on mobile device, whenever the cpu usage is below 5 percent, do you have any idea while the speed is to low ?

Comment: @Ata I would have to see your actual command and the ffmpeg log to be able to make any suggestions. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link here in a comment.

Comment: @Ata Use [libshine](https://github.com/toots/shine) instead of libmp3lame (first comment in answer). Or you could have both libmp3lame and libshine supported, but then you'll have to tell ffmpeg which encoder you want (I don't know which would have priority and therefore be automatically selected by default). `ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libshine output.mp3`.

Comment: the problem is that libshine is not well designed to be configured. I can not compile that

Comment: @Ata It appears to require automake, autoconf, make, and libtool as build dependencies. Run `./bootstrap` before `./configure`.